# Can cleos list all accounts related to a public key

Tags: cleos

I know I can get the public key from cleos for a given account but is the reverse possible?  Basically, I am trying to find all the account names associated with a public key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, you can just retrieve all the accounts for a given public key running the command `cleos get accounts EOS_PUB_KEY`

Another way to check the accounts for a public key, from an external application, is using the EOS RPC Api, check this out: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_key_accounts-1

Comment: I was using get account instead of get accounts :)

Comment: Is there a public domain I can use instead of 127.0.0.1  for **xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/history/get_key_accounts");** ?

Comment: I don't see a function to get all accounts but one could do:

`keys=\`cleos wallet keys | grep -v "[]\[]" | cut -f 2 -d "\""\`; for i in $keys; do cleos get accounts $i; done`

Comment: this was working only with a now deprecated plugin for the node (history plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it using `history_get_key_accounts`. The `history_get_key_accounts` api calls to `/v1/history/get_key_accounts`.

Please reference the following code.

```
const { Api, JsonRpc } = require('eosjs');
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));

const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://localhost:8888', { fetch });
const accounts = await rpc.history_get_key_accounts(public_key);
```